# Replace headlight mode selector

Tags: switches

Due to space constraints in my vehicle, I'd like to mount a 52mm gauge where my headlight selector switch currently sits. I'd still like to be able to minimally control my headlights, though. I pulled the switch out, and saw that it has 4 pins on the back, and the switch has 4 positions. I sequenced through the positions, and measured these states:

- Position 1: Pins 1 and 3 are connected (Automatic light mode)
- Position 2: Pins 1, 3 and 4 are connected (All lights off)
- Position 3: Pins 1 and 4 are connected (DRL's are on)
- Position 4: No pins connected (all lights are on)

I'm looking to replace this switch functionality with something substantially smaller. At the minimum I'd like to be able to replicate positions 1 and 2, and if possible positions 1, 2 and 4.

I have a 17mm wide by 40mm tall blanking plate to mount the switch and/or switches in.

An ideal switch will passively visually identify the mode my lights are currently in, by lining up with a decal on my dash.

Do switches exist that meet my physical constraints, or will I need to put a small circuit in here to replicate the switch behavior in a smaller package?

Comment: technically It's a Gray Code switch with only 4 of 8 combinations on 3 pins.,most likely custom OEM

Comment: How about a 12.7mm diam. rotary switch with 4 positions and a bunch of tiny 1N4148 diodes to convert to Gray Code? Unless you look at surplus vehicle switches , unlikely to find anything else.

Comment: Cost $12 , size fits and only 4 diodes but is decal linear or rotary?

Comment: I'd need to make a new decal. The current switch is rotary, but the current decal/face is 52mm wide.

Comment: it's a slam dunk then.  I can't draw schematics on iPad at the moment but any EE could with the 4 diodes for converting 1P4T to Gray Code https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/grayhill-inc/56SD36-01-2-AJS/GH7693-ND/4116187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your minimal situation, wire 1 to 3 and use a SPST toggle from 1/3 to 4.

For 1,2,4 you can use a **center-off** DPDT toggle switch as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flHPr0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Left = 1 
Center = 4
Right = 2

**(note: I assume pin #2 does nothing, since you didn't mention it)**

Edit: If you want to use a rotary switch and retain all 4 positions you could use something similar to Tony's suggestions of a Grayhill switch, however I would suggest a switch such as a 56D36-01-2-AJN with two poles (you can set the positions to 4 with a pin).

You don't need any other parts- just wire #1 to both commons and 3 or 4 to the other poles as desired (you can make them in any sequence you want).

However this series of switches is only rated for 200mA so you should check to make sure the current draw is acceptable.

Comment: What's a reliable way to measure the current on the circuit? Can I just plug the OEM rotary switch in to the connector and measure across pins 1/3 and 1/4 for the current draw?

Comment: Put a ammeter in **series** with each pin in turn and run through the 4 combinations (with the OEM switch). Maybe pin 1 is enough, but better safe than sorry. Then be sure to change your multimeter back to volts (move the test lead as well as the switch) or you will probably blow the fuse in your meter next time you use it.

Comment: Both of your listed suggestions (DPDT with center off) and the DP5T rotary switch seem like very accessible solutions.  Once I determine how much current I need to handle, I'll order up parts. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I ended up going with a DPDT center-off switch. It worked perfectly. I can now toggle between automatic / on / off with a single small switch. Thank you again for the help!